# wowza multiple files in one playlist

Tags: ffmpeg, playlist, wowza

Is it possible to create a stream in wowza from multiple files ? So these file would be played in a row after each other? As far as I know, I can only stream from one file being in the `content` directory..

1.) I would like to split that one file for my own reasons, to add some security to it etc... , and then to create the playlist from these multiple files and publish it for streaming.. so it won't take that much time comparing to the second way.

2.) Or do I need to put these multiple files back together and then publish the playlist?

I would also like to consider the time of the playlist being created even using a big file. I am using ffmpeg to split the file into smaller pieces using a script.

Therefore it would be automatic, when a user would request a stream, I run the script that splits the files and creates the playlist for user..

I hope I didn't take it from the wrong way. Help please

Comment: you could/should be able to stream from ffmpeg to a wowza server https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide, and "concat" the files together http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20concatenate%20(join,%20merge)%20media%20files but I know not more than this...

Answer (score 0):

On wowza website you can download [this module](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?145-How-to-do-scheduled-streaming-with-Stream-class-streams) to create playlists on server side without concating your files.

You may also want to check `com.wowza.wms.stream.publish.Stream` class which enables to you create a Stream on server side and attach playlist items to it. And [this post](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?187) will help you get started on how to create dynamic playlists if you need it.